# Redux state props value is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Hey everyone so I am in the works of creating a simulation of a user logging in. I am using redux logger and my state values that is logged is always the value I want to see however, when I am console.log(this.props)

I always get back undefined. My reducer has a state values that I have defined and have passed in as defaults. I am not sure why I am getting back undefined and just can't figure it out. Here is my code. Any help would be much appreciated I need to access these values but having it undefined does not work out.

I am going to condense down the boiler plate stuff like import statements etc. Also once again for context. All I am trying to do is inside of my component be able to access my state values that are defined inside of my reducer. For example, one of them is isLoginPending. When I am console.logging this.props.isLoginPending I would hope to either get the default value or the new Object.assigned value and not undefined. That is my ideal goal is to get a value inside of my component that is not undefined.

Here is my component

```
render() {
        let {email, password} = this.state;
        console.log("PROPS*****" + this.props.isLoginPending);
        return (
            <div className="form-wrapper" >
                <form onSubmit={this.submit} name="login-form">
                    <label htmlFor="login-form">Email</label>
                    <input onChange={this.changedEmail} type="email" />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="login-form"> Password </label>
                    <input onChange={this.changedPassword} type="password" />
                    <button type="submit">Login </button>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
       isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
       isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
       isloginError: state.isloginError
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        login: (email, password) => dispatch(login(email ,password))
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Reducer

```
 export default function (state = {
        isLoginPending: false,
        isLoginSuccess: false,
        isLoginError: null
    }, action)
     {
        switch(action.type) {
            case constants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            console.log("state" + state.isLoginPending);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoginSuccess: action.isLoginSuccess})

            case constants.LOGIN_PENDING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoginPending: action.isLoginPending})

            case constants.LOGIN_ERROR:

            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoginError: action.isLoginError})

            default: 
            return state
        }
    }
```

Actions

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loginPending(true));
        dispatch(loginSuccess(false));
        dispatch(loginError(null));

    sendLoginRequest(email, password, error => {
        dispatch(loginPending(false));
        if(!error) {
            dispatch(loginSuccess(true));
        } else {
            dispatch(loginError(error));
        }
    });
    }
}

const sendLoginRequest = (email, password, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(email === 'admin@admin.com' && password === 'password') {
            return callback(null);
        } 

        else {
            return callback(new Error("invalid email or password"));
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

** edit **

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
```

root reducer that is passed into store

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginForm: emailReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Where is the definition of your store? How does the Provider look like?

Comment: Please take this in the nicest way possible but I am absolutely sure it does not have to do with my store or my provider. My actions and reducers are linking up I am just getting back undefined.

Comment: I don't see the need for the defensive stance ;) I am trying to investigate if your `mapStateToProps` is really mapped to the correct state that you seem to expect. However, your reducer returns an object, now if you use the combineReducers, then you have a state that is based on multiple different keys, and your store could indicate what the structure of your state is at that time

Comment: Sorry I do not mean to be in a defensive stance. I will edit and post my store and my combineReducers method.

Comment: So with the update, shouldn't the `mapStateToProps` point to `state.loginForm.isLoginPending`?

Comment: you are passing `loginForm` as a prop though

Comment: Wow. You are absolutely correct. I cannot believe I missed this. I am so sorry for not providing more context from the beginning. Please post this as an answer so I can accept. Man do I feel stupid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is your `mapStateToProps` object, namely, you are expecting the flags to be on the rootstate

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
       isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
       isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
       isloginError: state.isloginError
    }
}
```

However, when we see your root reducer, you have a multilevel state that adds these flags inside the `state.loginForm`

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginForm: emailReducer
});
```

So changing your mapStateToProps like this should do

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
       isLoginPending: state.loginForm.isLoginPending,
       isLoginSuccess: state.loginForm.isLoginSuccess,
       isloginError: state.loginForm.isloginError
    }
}
```

Comment: For those using TypeScript:
I had this same issue. I was using the sub state as the method property type for mapStateToProps so intellisense didn't alert me to my error.
i.e. RootState is composed of (using combineReudcers) SubState1 and SubState2. For my component, mapStateToProps originally had a method property type of SubState1, which was incorrect. RootState is the property type.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `loginForm` as a store to the connected components via your `rootReducer`:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginForm: emailReducer
});
```

So inside `mapstateToProps` you could do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
       isLoginPending: state.loginForm.isLoginPending,
       isLoginSuccess: state.loginForm.isLoginSuccess,
       isloginError: state.loginForm.isloginError
    }
}
```